# Is it possible to publish a Visual Studio template extension through the command line?

Tags: templates, command-line-interface, vsix, marketplace

Since the end of 2018, we have the possibility of publishing extensions to the VS marketplace through the command-line.

There's a pretty neat guide on how to do that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-publishing-a-visual-studio-extension-via-command-line?view=vs-2019).

How you specify a category for your extension is through the `publishManifest.json` file. You can see the JSON schema for it [here](http://json.schemastore.org/vsix-publish).

The problem is that, as you can see in the schema, you can only provide subcategories for the `Tools` category of the Marketplace.

Whatever extension you publish, the marketplace will put it under `Tools`. If you try to enter subcategories for other extension types such as `ASP.NET` or `AJAX` you'll get an error during publishing.

The question is - is it possible to publish a VS template through the CLI with a proper category as of today?